# C - Write to file number of occurrences of character

Tags: c, string, file, encoding, char

I am writing an encoding function, that takes a file descriptor from the source file, and a FILE* as the destination file. If the input file has this: `AABBBcccc`then I should write `2A3B4c` in the output file. (number of the same consecutive character).
I managed to do this but my only problem is the number of occurrence for the first letter gets a +1... So I would get : `3A3B4c`. The function returns the total number of characters written in outt.

```
int encode_aux(int fd1, char *buffer, FILE *outt)                               
{                                                                               
    size_t c = read(fd1, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);                           
    char previous;  //to check if the next character is the same                                                            
    int count = 0;  //number of occurence of the same character                                                             
    int total = 0;  //total number of chars written in the output file                                                            
    while (c != 0)                                                              
    {                                                                           
        for (size_t i = 0; i < c; i++)                                          
        {                                                                       
            if (count == 0)                                                     
            {                                                                   
                previous = buffer[i];                                           
                count += 1;                                                     
            }                                                                   
            if (count != 0)                                                     
            {                                                                   
                if (previous == buffer[i])                                      
                {                                                               
                    count += 1;                                                 
                }                                                               
                else                                                            
                {                                                               
                    if (i == 0)                                                 
                    {                                                           
                        count -= 1;                                             
                    }                                                           
                    if (count != 1)                                             
                    {                                                           
                        total += fprintf(outt, "%d", count);                    
                    }                                                           
                    total += fprintf(outt, "%c", previous);                     
                    previous = buffer[i];                                       
                    count = 1;                                                  
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
        buffer[c] = '\0';                                                       
        c = read(fd1, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);                              
    }                                                                           
    return total;                                                               
}

int encode(const char *file_in, const char *file_out)                       
{                                                                               
    FILE *out = fopen(file_out, "w");                                           
    char buff[4096];                                                            
    int fd = open(file_in, O_RDONLY);                                           
    if (fd == -1 || out == NULL)                                                
    {                                                                           
        return -1;                                                              
    }                                                                           
    int tot = encode_aux(fd, buff, out);                                        
    if (close(fd) == -1 || fclose(out) != 0)                                    
    {                                                                           
        return -1;                                                              
    }                                                                           
    return tot;                                                                 
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(buffer) - 1` is `sizeof(char *) - 1` - it's the size of a pointer to char minus 1. `the same` So you are doing `char buffer [sizeof(char*) - 1]; encode(..., buffer, ...)`?

Comment: I don't want to get the "\n". I added the calling function

Comment: You did `char buff[4096];`. `sizeof(buffer)` inside `encode_aux` is size of a pointer, not the size of memory behind buffer pointer - `sizeof(char*)` for example it's `4` on 32bit computer or like it's `8` for 64-bit computer. So you are not reading 4095 characters at a time - you are for example reading 3 or 7 characters depending on your architecture. `I don't want to get the "\n"` - `read` doesn't parse the data, you can manually ignore `if (buffer[i] == '\n') continue;` the data you don't want to parse, of for example use `isspace` from `ctype.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (count == 0)                                                     
        {                                                                   
            previous = buffer[i];                                           
            count += 1;                                                     
        }                                                                   
        if (count != 0)                                                     
        {                                                                   
            if (previous == buffer[i])                                      
            {                                                               
                count += 1;                                                 
            }
```

When `count == 0` then `count = 1`. Then you check `count != 0`, cause you just did `count += 1`, because `count` was 0. Then `if (previous == buffer[i])`, which also will be always true, because you just did `previous = buffer[i]` int he first if. Then you increment count again.

I think you miss an else:

```
        if (count == 0)                                                     
        {                                                                   
            previous = buffer[i];                                           
            count += 1;                                                     
        } else                                                      
        if (count != 0)                                                     
        {                                                                   
            if (previous == buffer[i])                                      
            {                                                               
                count += 1;                                                 
            }
```

Notes:

- I think you are mixing `fgets` with `read` calls. The `buffer[c] = '\0';` is unneeded, the `read` call just reads bytes from the file descriptors, whatever they are, and if `c` will be too bug for `buffer`, it will be out-of-bounds access.
- You are not printing the count of the last character of the file. It just so happens, that your file ends with a newline - the `previous` is set to newline on the last execution of your loop. If your file wouldn't end with w newline, the count of the last character won't be printed.

Comment: Add between the last `}` and `return total` add `if (count != 0) total += fprintf(outt, "%c", previous);`